# Will I be able to use these wheels from my 2004 Saturn L300 on my 2005 Pontiac G6?

Tags: wheels, pontiac, saturn, g6, swap

The tires on my G6 are 225 r50 17. One of them blew out today and I have fairly new tires on my Saturn that I'd like to swap. The Saturn tires are 215 R55 16, would I be able to use these tires?

I'm going to eventually switch them back to the Saturn when I sell it, so this wouldn't be perfect. Just trying to save a bit of money for the next few weeks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is maybe.  The rims may not be compatible, even though the bolt circle (5x110mm) is the same.

However, I'm showing an ET42 offset on the G6 with 17s, and ET45 offset for the L300.

That may not be enough difference to matter.  The L300 tires are also over a half inch smaller in diameter, which makes for an additional 17 revolutions per mile.  There will be a 2.5% error (approx) in your speedometer and odometer.

I can't recommend such a swap without evaluating all clearances at all steering angles, but the 3mm offset difference in the rims is likely negligible.

Comment: It's worth noting that the flat was a rear tire so I could put 2 on the back and it wouldn't interfere with the speedometer, right? or would it be better to just go with all four

Comment: Also remember, there may be fitment issues with clearance of the rim to brakes.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Good call!  The rim offset is additional, so I doubt that's a problem.  That year G6 came with 16" wheel packages, and my auto parts store only shows one size replacement rotors in the catalog.  I still can't endorse it, but if I *were* to do it on my own recognizance, I would certainly swap all four rims.